# How to change screen resolution scaling in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, display, display-resolution, customization, settings

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04. I want to change my screen resolution scaling from 1.00 to 0.75. It was very easy in 16.04 version. Please help me to change the scaling.